# SSDT Publish Window: What does checkbox ENABLE mean?

Tags: ssdt, deployment, visual-studio-2015

In the Visual Studio 2015 SSDT "Advanced Publish Settings" Window, Tab General, "Advanced Deployment Options" there are several checkboxes in the column "ENABLED" we can check or uncheck.

Most of the descriptions in there (that are also documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) say something like this:

> "Specifies whether differences in the database collation should be
>   **ignored or updated** when you publish to a database."

[image]

Now, it's completely undefined what exact consequences checking this box has: ignored OR updated? Does it ENABLE IGNORE or ENABLE UPDATE?

Does anyone know?

It is so annoying that people create software and never ever notice that their wording is misleading and unclear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The checkbox applies to each option "positively" so that e.g. ticking "script database collation" will generate the appropriate statements to alter collation settings. If not ticked, the deployment will ignore those differences by not scripting the changes.

Comment: HI, do you by chance have any reference to look up? I could not find it.

Comment: @Magier The "enabled" refers to the option, not to parts of the option's definition. You either enable the scripting of the DB collation, or you do not enable the scripting of the DB collation. It seems reasonable to interpret this as meaning "scripting DB collation = updating" (you aren't ignoring something when you issue statements to do it) and "not scripting the DB collation = ignoring" (you can't alter something if no statements are scripted out to do it). I'm not being snide/rude, just pointing out why there is likely no reference for this. Also test both ways & check the _Create script.

Comment: [sqlpackage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) has some docs on these items, including `ScriptDatabaseCollation`